# Moodle display course completion status in MyCourses list

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to modify our moodle home page to show the status of a course (completed, etc) adjacent to all of the courses a user is registered in.

I'm on Moodle 3.1

On our Home page we display a list of enrolled courses ("my courses"); but i can't seem to find the file that is generating that list.

I tried modifying blocks / course_list but no luck. Does anyone know what php page generates this section?

The code i'm attempting to add looks like:

```
          $cinfo = new completion_info($course);
          $iscomplete = $cinfo->is_course_complete($USER->id);
          // Display something to the user if is complete
```